# how can I make the first Query match the second one Date format mm/dd/yyy

Tags: sql, date, format

how can I make the first one match the second one

```
declare @lastDayprevquart date select @lastDayprevquart = convert(nvarchar(MAX),(DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)),101) 
SELECT @lastDayprevquart

select convert(nvarchar(MAX),(DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)),101)
```

----final result should looks like 01/01/2017

Answer (score 0):

Convert is more for formatting of display.. You will need CAST to able to filter

```
declare @lastDayprevquart date select @lastDayprevquart = convert(nvarchar(MAX),(DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)),101) 
SELECT cast(@lastDayprevquart as date)

select cast(convert(nvarchar(MAX),(DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)),101) as date)
```

both should show as 2017-01-01

your clean formula should be

```
cast(DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) as date)
```

But if you really want mm/dd/yyy format

then change data type of your variable

```
declare @lastDayprevquart nvarchar(max)

select @lastDayprevquart = convert(nvarchar(MAX),(DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)),101) 
select @lastDayprevquart

select convert(nvarchar(MAX),(DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)),101)
```

Noting that if you use this as your criteria sql will read this as string and not date type. Convert is more for display